# How to use a different alphabet for Base32 classes?

Tags: python, c++, base64, crypto++, base32

On python when I do:

```
encoded = base64.b32encode("1ACC64E9510C32CE8E34".decode('hex'))
```

I get `DLGGJ2KRBQZM5DRU`. While on Crypto++:

```
std::string decoded2;
std::string first_20="1ACC64E9510C32CE8E34";

StringSource ssv(first_20, true /*pumpAll*/,
    new HexDecoder(
        new StringSink(decoded2)
    ) // HexDecoder
); // StringSource
boost::algorithm::to_lower(decoded2);

StringSource ss( decoded2, true,

    new Base32Encoder(
        new StringSink(hash_sink)
    ) // Base64Decoder
); // StringSource

std::cout<<"encoded raw:"<<hash_sink<<std::endl;
```

I get `DMGGJ4MTBS3N7DTW` which is wrong.

Is there a way I can encode the string above in c++ and get the same result as python does it ?

Comment: please always post codes with header files. (BTW, I didnt downvote).

Comment: The header files are

`#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <rsa.h>
#include <osrng.h>
#include <files.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <hex.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp>
using namespace std;
#include <base64.h>
#include <rsa.h>
#include <sha.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <base32.h>`

Comment: how does this question not show any research effort ? 
I've even asked on the cryptopp issue tracker and they say the functions are not the same [github](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/534)

Comment: where did you define `hash_sink`?

Comment: hash_sink is just an empty string to save the result. I've been told that I should initialize the Crypto++ Base32 implementation to use a different alphabet than the default.But I don't know how to do that in the context of the above code

Comment: We added a `Base32HexEncoder` and `Base32HexDecoder` at [Commit 8530b58eddbe](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/8530b58eddbe). The classes support RFC 4648, Base 32 Encoding with Extended Hex Alphabet (from section 7). But the alphabet in the RFC is not the alphabet you ar using in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution github

```
static const CryptoPP::byte ALPHABET[]          = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"; // Most libraries use RFC4648.

const std::string decode( const std::string& encoded )
{
    std::string decoded;

    static int decoding_array[256];
    CryptoPP::Base32Decoder::InitializeDecodingLookupArray(decoding_array, 
                               ALPHABET, 
                               32, 
                               true); // false = case insensitive

    CryptoPP::Base32Decoder b32decoder;
    CryptoPP::AlgorithmParameters dp = CryptoPP::MakeParameters(
                                       CryptoPP::Name::DecodingLookupArray(),
                                       (const int *)decoding_array,
                                       false);
    b32decoder.IsolatedInitialize(dp); 

    b32decoder.Attach( new CryptoPP::StringSink( decoded ) );
    b32decoder.Put( (std::uint8_t*)encoded.c_str(), encoded.size() );
    b32decoder.MessageEnd();

    return decoded;
}
```

I hope the guy who downvoted me can also see this.
I'm very new to crypto++ and cryptography as a whole.

Comment: This seems to be the same alphabet as the default one: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"`. Maybe you should precisely state what you want instead of stating "it is wrong". Also see [`base32.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/base32.cpp) source file.

Comment: In the default mode, I just get a different result. And I didn't know it was a alphabet issue at first. Untill I opened an issue on cryptopp  repo.I was also asked to what advantages does using this specific alphabet as default. I guess he wanted to determine whether to make it the default which it is not.

Comment: if a mod could also delete this post, I will gladly appreciate it. I don't understand why the down-votes, while it's a question which relates to complex stuff that new users will never figure at first hand.

Comment: I am disappointed by this community for a second time since  a while ago.
I have never received an answer from here, most of the times it's just me answering myself. Do most people come here just to up-vote and down-vote instead of helping users ?.
What if English is not my first language ??
I think this will be the last question I ever ask here, nobody even gave an up-vote to my answer.

Comment: I think you can flag the question and ask the moderators delete it. Search the web page for the word "flag".